# How to check for exactly 1 occurence of a string with unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, chai, enzyme

I am creating a unit test for my reactjs-app with enzyme and chai:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComp {...props}>
    </MyComp>
);

expect(wrapper.debug()).to.contain("hello");
```

How can I assert for exactly 1 occurrence of the word 'hello'?

Comment: I believe that we can skip chai's `contain` and do something like `expect((wrapper.debug().match(/hello/g) || []).length).to.equal(1)` for flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to test full rendering of your component:

```
// GIVEN
const expectedElement = shallow(<div>Hello</div>);

// WHEN
const actualElement = shallow(<MyComp {...props} />);

// THEN
expect(actualElement.html()).to.equal(expectedElement.html());
```

It gives you much better coverage than `contains` approach. But you need to sometimes user regular expressions to wipe out React empty HTML templates or generated CSS classes (if you or your third party components are using them).

If you use Jest, there is also library/plugin that does pre-generation of expected element and you can check it into source control. Actual rendering is than compared with this pre-rendered component every test run. But I didn't use this approach myself.